Text programing in Pure Data
I don't like visual programming, but I really liked Pure data. I noticed that projects in Pure Data can be opened in text editors and the syntax in their text is not particularly difficult to understand. Please tell me if there are any reference books on this type of programming in Pure Data and is it even ethical to program this way?
I will also attach here a project that I opened in Pure Data. If you copy this code to any text file, then change the file extension from .txt to .pd and the code will turn into a Pure Data project.
#N canvas 0 0 1920 997 12;
#X obj 856 198 *~;
#X obj 849 264 *~ 0.25;
#X obj 864 339 dac~;
#X obj 850 161 osc~ 440;
#X connect 0 0 1 0;
#X connect 1 0 2 0;
#X connect 1 0 2 1;
#X connect 3 0 0 0;
#X connect 3 0 0 1;


It looks like an internal representation of their data model.

That is, this type of programming is not entirely ethical?

TL;DR: Don't do it.
It's obviously possible to edit the patch files, the syntax is not difficult. But it's not really practical because the interconnections between the objects (the patch cords) are set at the end of the file and they reference the objects by their line number in the file. So if you add an atom (a box object in Pd) manually by inserting a new line, all the connections referencing objects below that line must be incremented by 1 to point to the same atom as before.

can you tell me more about the device interconnections between the objects?
